# When simulating a full EBS volume for Kafka, the service doesn't explode. Why?

Tags: apache-kafka

We're working on fault tolerance testing for our Kafka cluster. I'm trying to simulate a full volume for the service, and observe where and why it fails. So to start, I did a `fallocate -l <bytes> /data/big.file` and then used `df` to ensure 0 bytes remained available.

Nothing happened. I assumed because we'd had load running on this cluster for days and the `retention.hours=72` was too short -- data was likely being deleted as new data came in. So, I updated this setting to `-1`, to disable deletion, and restarted this broker. Still, nothing happened (as in, nothing detrimental). To make doubly sure, I tried

`./kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper 10.0.0.1 --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name __consumer_offsets --add-config 'retention.ms=8640000000000'`

I applied this setting to all topics. This should make the retention of 10 days. However, even after 12 hours of full load hitting our cluster, I see no evidence that the volume has filled up - Kafka is entirely healthy, at least as far as metrics can show me.

What am I missing? Are there other settings I should be modifying? I don't necessarily want to break the system for the sake of breaking it, but I *do* want to understand why it's healthy with a completely full data volume.

As for how I'm determining the system is healthy:

- ISR remains unchanged, 3 replicas (replica factor of 3)
- In the ISR, this broker is still present
- This broker is also still the leader for several partitions

Answer (score 0):

Few possibilities:-

1. Make sure the broker config **log.retention.bytes** is set to **-1**.
2. Make sure **fallocate -l  /data/big.file** points to the disk which is used by kafka.log.dirs. I hope you are not clearing some other part of filesystem which is not being used by kafka at all.
3. Make sure your topic( to which you are loading) is not log compacted and has enough retention.
4. Make sure there is no data skew. In other words: push lot of data to a partition whose leader is the node which you are monitoring/expecting to fail. You can use some linux command (netstat or tcpdump) to ensure that data is really coming to the expected broker.
5. Also check the broker logs

If all above this are checked than the broker should fail once the disk is full.

Hope this helps.